# Why is the user details vanishes from the Firestore?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am using `Firebase PhoneAuth` for user registration with my app. Users are verified successfully and started using the app without any issues. But, It happened to me a couple of times that user details vanished from `Firestore` database, not all users details have gone though. When I check the collection `users` in the `Firestore`, the document does exist for the user but some data was gone, in fact, it's overwritten the old data as if this is new user registration (However, the User UID under the Authentication is remain same). For example, the default value is `user_type = "customer"`, as you can see in the `fun signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential: PhoneAuthCredential)`. Later I change this value accordingly to my need and when this issue happens the changes I made to this field and other fields are changed back to the default values.

Following is the code in my `SignInWithPhone` which will be called from the `SplashScreen`

```
class SigninWithPhoneActivity: BaseActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivitySignInWithPhoneBinding
    private lateinit var mAuth: FirebaseAuth
    var code = ""
    var number = ""
    var phoneNumber = ""
    var storedOtpID = ""
    private lateinit var resendToken: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivitySignInWithPhoneBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        }

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        binding.btnGetOtp.setOnClickListener {

            code = binding.etCountryCode.text.toString().trim()
            number = binding.etMobileNumber.text.toString().trim()
            phoneNumber = code + number

            if (number.isNotEmpty()) {
                binding.etMobileNumber.isEnabled = false
                binding.flOtp.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.btnGetOtp.visibility = View.GONE
                binding.btnSignIn.visibility = View.VISIBLE

                sendVerificationCode(phoneNumber)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a valid mobile number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }

        binding.btnSignIn.setOnClickListener {

            val otp = binding.etOtp.text.toString().trim()

            if (otp.isNotEmpty() || otp.length != 6) {
                verifyVerificationCode(otp)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter the OTP received through SMS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show()
            }
        }

    }

    private val mCallBack: PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks =
        object : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

            override fun onVerificationCompleted(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
                val code = credential.smsCode

                if (code != null) {
                    binding.etOtp.setText(code)
                    binding.pbOtp.visibility = View.GONE
                }
            }

            override fun onVerificationFailed(p0: FirebaseException) {

                binding.etMobileNumber.isEnabled = true
                binding.flOtp.visibility = View.GONE
                binding.btnGetOtp.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.btnSignIn.visibility = View.GONE

                Toast.makeText(this@SigninWithPhoneActivity, "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show()
            }

            override fun onCodeSent(otpID: String, token: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken) {
                super.onCodeSent(otpID, token)

                Toast.makeText(
                    this@SigninWithPhoneActivity,
                    "OTP is send to your number",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()
                storedOtpID = otpID
                resendToken = token
            }
        }

    private fun sendVerificationCode(phoneNumber: String) {

        binding.pbOtp.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        Toast.makeText(this@SigninWithPhoneActivity, "Sending OTP", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        val options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(mAuth!!)
            .setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
            .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .setActivity(this)
            .setCallbacks(mCallBack)
            .build()
        PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options)

    }

    private fun verifyVerificationCode(code: String) {

        Toast.makeText(
            this@SigninWithPhoneActivity,
            "Verifying credentials",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show()

        val credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(storedOtpID, code)
        signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential)
    }

    private fun signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {

                    val firebaseUser: FirebaseUser = task.result!!.user!!
                    val userPreliminaryDetails = User(
                        firebaseUser.uid,
                        user_type = "customer",
                        mobile = binding.etMobileNumber.text.toString()
                    )

                    FirestoreClass().checkIfUserAlreadyExist(
                        this@SigninWithPhoneActivity,
                        firebaseUser.uid,
                        userPreliminaryDetails
                    )

                } else {

                    showErrorSnackBar(task.exception!!.message.toString(), true)

                    if (task.exception is FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {

                        binding.etMobileNumber.isEnabled = true
                        binding.flOtp.visibility = View.GONE
                        binding.etOtp.text?.clear()
                        binding.btnGetOtp.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        binding.btnGetOtp.text = "Resend OTP"
                        binding.btnSignIn.visibility = View.GONE

                        Toast.makeText(this, "OTP entered is wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                    }
                }
            }
    }

    fun userRegistrationSuccess() {
        finish()
        startActivity(Intent(this, ServiceAreaActivity::class.java))
        Toast.makeText(this, "Signed Up successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    fun userSignInSuccess() {
        finish()
        startActivity(Intent(this, ServiceAreaActivity::class.java))
        Toast.makeText(this, "Signed in successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

    }

}
```

EDIT:

The following function is called to check if the user already exists and accordingly sign in or register a new user.

```
        fun checkIfUserAlreadyExist(
        activity: SigninWithPhoneActivity, userId: String, userDetails: User
    ) {

        mFireStore.collection("users")
            .whereEqualTo(Constants.USER_ID, userId)
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                if (document.documents.size > 0) {
                    activity.userSignInSuccess()
                } else {
                    FirestoreClass().registerUser(activity, userDetails)
                }

            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                
            }
    }



    private fun registerUser(activity: SigninWithPhoneActivity, userInfo: User) {

    mFireStore.collection(Constants.USERS)
        .document(userInfo.user_id)
        .set(userInfo, SetOptions.merge())
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            activity.userRegistrationSuccess()
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { e ->
            activity.hideProgressDialog()
        }
}
```

Comment: I cannot see any code that adds data to Firestore.

Comment: @AlexMamo I have added those functions. Please take a look, thank you.

Comment: First of all, stop ignoring errors. Use `Log.d(TAG, e.message!!);`. Do you get something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the ignoring errors. I added the given line of code in all my functions wherever I missed it. No, I didn't get any error when I sign in to my app, I logged out and then enter the phone number and received OTP, enter the OTP and verified successfully. There were no errors shown in the `Logcat`.  The issue which I mentioned in my question doesn't happen always, but it happened a couple of times and I'm worried if that will happen again. So, I was thinking that I was doing it wrong. Now I hope there are no errors in my code as you have not pointed out anything about it.

Comment: @AlexMamo I have posted another question regarding the `Log.d(TAG, e.message!!)` https://stackoverflow.com/q/69796001/13935956

Comment: @AlexMamo Can I assume my code is OK, if so then, can you guess why is that happening?

Comment: Is it happening if the same user tries to register twice with the same account?