# I do not get the error in the Logcat when a document of a user is not found in the collection but app crashes

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I use `Firebase PhoneAuth` in my app and the following function is called after the verification is successfully finished. While I was doing some trial, I deleted the entire document of a user, who is authenticated using the phone number, from the collection called `"users"`. Then when I try to open the app, the app crashes and gets `java.lang.NullPointerException` error. However, it doesn't show the error message for `Log.d("Tag", e.message!!)` in the `.addOnFailureListener`. How can I catch this type of error? Isn't `.addOnFailureListener` supposed to consider this as an error?

```
    fun getUserDetail(fragment: HomeFragment) {

    mFireStore.collection(Constants.USERS)
        .document(getCurrentUserID())
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
            val user = document.toObject(User::class.java)!!
            fragment.successUserDetail(user)
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { e ->
            Log.d("Tag", e.message!!)
            fragment.hideProgressDialog()
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that NullPointerException most likely at the following line of code:

```
 val user = document.toObject(User::class.java)!!
```

And it makes sense since you say you have deleted the user from the collection.

> Isn't .addOnFailureListener supposed to consider this as an error?

No, that NPE is not a failure, it just indicates that you have called a method on a document that doesn't exist, in other words, which is null. However, a failure may occur when, for example, the Firebase servers reject your request due to improper security rules. I have also written an article regarding that called:

- [How to fix Firestore Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-fix-firestore-error-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions-777d591f404)

If you want to avoid that NPE, in a Kotlin style, you shouldn't use the `!!` operator but:

```
document?.let {
    val user = it.toObject(User::class.java)
    fragment.successUserDetail(user)
}
```